# PostgreSQL update takes too long

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a query update with limit 1000 on ny select query:

UPDATE id SET satus = 201 WHERE uniquecode in (ids..)

I already have index for my query but it took so long

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_idx ON public.id USING btree (id);


  ->  Index Scan using id_idx on id (cost=0.56..4280.29 rows=500 width=811) (actual time=0.758..11.244 rows=500 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((id)::numeric = ANY (ids..)
Planning Time: 3.087 ms
Execution Time: 1543.567 ms
```

i need execute below 1000 ms

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the index you want is on the `uniquecode` column, rather than the `id` column:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_idx ON public.id USING btree (uniquecode);
```

Note that if `id` be the primary key of your table, then it already should have a btree index on it.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake with my query. but, i will try it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the complete execution plan, nor did you show the actual query, but if the scraps of information you show are accurate, the time is not spent in the index scan, but in the update itself.

Probably there are lots of indexes on the table and/or long running triggers.